# django - mysql selecting data from db does not work well

Tags: django

In main.html:

```
{% for item in count_list %}
    {{ item }}<br>
{% endfor %}
```

In views.py:

```
def four(request):
    count_list = PDivContent.objects.filter(divv = '5')
    return render(request, 'main.html', {'count_list': count_list})
```

The problem is that the count_list list, contains data repeated for twice like this:

```
طلا و جواهرات
بدلیجات و نقره سرا
اجناس کادویی
اسباب بازی فروشی
صنایع دستی
فروش و تعمیر ساعت
طلا و جواهرات
بدلیجات و نقره سرا
صنایع دستی
اجناس کادویی
اسباب بازی فروشی
```

How can I solve it?

models.py:

```
class PDivContent(models.Model):
    chest = models.IntegerField()
    divv = models.IntegerField()
    txt = models.TextField()
    img = models.TextField()
    symbol = models.TextField()


    def __str__(self):
        return self.txt


    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'p_div_content'
```

And in the db, data are not repeated for twice.

Comment: This very much depends on your models.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have the same data entered twice?

Comment: yes I have chacked it right now again!

Comment: That is the only possible explanation I can see, you could verify this by adding a new entry and see if thats duplicated (although if your save functionality saves twice then it would still show the issue)

Comment: Could you update the output of your list to also show the primary key of the table row? i.e. temporarily changing the template to output `{{ item.id }} {{ item.txt }}<br>` That way it would be easier to see whether the same rows are shown twice and also, for people like me who can't read the language, to better compare the results.

Comment: Well, with fallowing {{ item.img }} I found thaht data have been imported to db for twice.

Comment: are you aware of usage of managed = False ? and applied migration properly?

Answer (score 0):

How about trying `.distinct()` in your query?

```
def four(request):
    count_list = PDivContent.objects.filter(divv = '5').distinct()
    return render(request, 'main.html', {'count_list': count_list})
```